# How can I navigate from Blazor Page to Xaml page in .net Maui Blazor hybrid?

Tags: blazor, maui

as the title says . if I have a .razor page and a xaml page and I want to navigate from razor to xaml and vice versa.

Comment: The blazor pages will be displayed on a [Page containing a BlazorWebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-hybrid-apps-with-net-maui). So going TO a .razor page is as simple as going to that page (containing BlazorWebView), with a URI specifying the .razor page. FROM a .razor page is trickier. I didn't find a STANDARD way to do that ...

Comment: ... until someone suggests a better idea, maybe could make "fake URIs" that represent the desired Maui page, and detect them in [a handler attached to blazorWebView.UrlLoading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-maui). You'd change the code shown in that doc to first test the URI for some non-standard pattern that represents the desired page.

Comment: This is extremely painful.  I created service/class I inject into the .razor to call the shell command to navigate to the xaml.  Not ideal.  When the back button is pressed on the XAML page, I don't have a way to know on the .razor page to unregister events done in the .razor oninitialized method

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: on the blazor page:

```
@code{
private void GoTo()
{
    App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new FileManagerPage());
}}
```

Comment: How to do the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

Using BlazorWebView to Navigate to .razor pages is too slow and not feel native... Using MainPage.Current.Navigation is good and feel smooth.

```cs
//Current Page
MainPage.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new HighLightsXamlPage());

//SecondPage
public partial class HighLightsXamlPage : ContentPage
{ 
    public HighLightsXamlPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
    }
    public static HighLightsXamlPage Current { get; private set; }
    public async void GoBack()
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

HighLightsXamlPage Content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Bible.Maui.Blazor.HighLightsXamlPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui;assembly=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bible.Maui.Blazor.Pages.Highlights"
    Title="HighLightsXamlPage">
    <Grid>
        <b:BlazorWebView x:Name="rzor" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">

            <b:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <b:RootComponent ComponentType="{x:Type local:HighLightsPage}" Selector="#app" />
            </b:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </b:BlazorWebView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```