# How to navigate from a xaml page to a blazor page in .NET Blazor Maui Hybrid

Tags: .net, xaml, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

Does anyone know how we can navigate from a xaml page to a specific razor page inside a Blazor Maui Hybrid application?
I know that it is possible to navigate from a blazor page to a xaml page according to this [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960973/how-can-i-navigate-from-blazor-page-to-xaml-page-in-net-maui-blazor-hybrid) but can't find a way to do it the other way around.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the code below to navigate from a xaml page to a blazor page.

```
 <Button class="btn btn-secondary" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
}
```

For more details， you may refer to the link:"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0".I will follow up if there are any problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I believe this only works when navigating to a xaml page. How would I for example navigate to the Counter.razor page that is located in the pages folder in a .NET Maui Blazor app starting from the MainPage?

Comment: The blazor pages will be displayed on [a Page containing a BlazorWebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-hybrid-apps-with-net-maui). So going to a  .razor page may mean go to that page (containing BlazorWebView), with a URI specifying the .razor page.